# Above pic keeps on going out of div

Tags: html, css

I made my website responsive that will look good in all devices. However, whenever I try to scale down the size of my web browser. The above image below an image, goes out of the div. Tried the overflow: hidden in the div but it doesn't show the image. See the jsfiddle and resize the square frames, you'll see that it goes out of the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/view02/hzv2jht0/

```css
#deets img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#deets {
  margin-top: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#text { 
  margin-left: 250px; 
}

#text img { 
  margin-top: -55%; 
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="deets">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-1.jpg">
  <div id="text">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-6.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this? https://jsfiddle.net/7v3rhmez/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the `margin-left: 250px` you set on the `#text`. `px` units are fixed, in this case use relative units like `%` instead:

```css
#deets img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#deets {
  margin-top: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  margin-left: 25%; /* modified */
  /* display: flex; better way to horizontally center the content */
  /* justify-content: center; comment out the margin-left above if you want to use these two lines */
}

#text img {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -55%; 
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="deets">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-1.jpg">
  <div id="text">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-6.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#deets` div.

```
#deets {
  margin-top: -40px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
  /* add this if you want to stop it running out of the containing div */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or if you want to keep both images showing in entirety, you'll want to change `#text` CSS

```
#text  {     
  /* margin-left: 250px;  */
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

If it must be 250px from the left, you'll want to add a media query and target a lower screen width.

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
  ...
}
```